# One of my questions tagged incorrectly and I can't edit it -- why?

Tags: bug, tags, questions

While looking at my older questions, I noticed that [one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63450157/is-there-an-alternative-for-zipiterable-when-the-iterable-consists-of-million) was tagged with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) but it has nothing to do with JavaScript at all. The question is about Python. I don't think I tagged it myself. I checked the history but couldn't find anything. Anyways, let's assume that I mistakenly added the JavaScript tag when I asked the question. Now, I want to remove it but it doesn't let me do so. No error or warning messages; the edit page closes and the tag is still there. Why could this happen?

Comment: Indeed, it does not appear that the [[tag:javascript]] tag was ever added to the question, and it was not tagged as such in the initial revision. Very strange, definitely  a bug how that tag showed up on your question.

Comment: What happens if you add another tag in place of it? Are there 6 tags then

Comment: Possibly related: [Spurious unkillable tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325757)

Comment: @Nick It says "Please enter no more than 5 tags."

Comment: I removed the python tag then added it again. And then I was able to remove the javascript tag.

Comment: You should totally drop [python] and try [javascript]... [or was it jquery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/194720)? :)

Comment: Hey I dropped Python and tried jQuery. It's the best thing ever!